# C++ inner class; no symbol in "nm -C" output

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, inner-classes

I am studying the details of C++ template instantiation by `gcc 4.8.1` with the option [`-frepo`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html#Template-Instantiation) on Linux. As I understand it, this option does some house cleaning of template instantiations so each instantiation is present in the linked binary only once, even if it is implicitly instantiated in several translation units. For specific context, please refer to these example files:

```
// file: template.h
template <typename T>
class Box {
public:
    void func (const T & t) {}        // member function

    template <T t>
    T func_tmpl () { return t; }      // member function template

    template <T t>
    class inner {                     // inner class template
    public:
        const static T value = t;
    };
};
```

and

```
// file: main.cpp
#include "template.h"

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Box<int> b;
    b.func(3);                        // member function invocation
    int x = b.func_tmpl<7>();         // member function temple instantiation
    Box<int>::inner<5> g;             // inner class template instantiation
    int y = g.value;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile (`g++ -frepo -c main.cpp`) and then inspect the symbols (`nm -C main.o`) I find:

```
0000000000000000 T main
                 U Box<int>::func(int const&)
                 U int Box<int>::func_tmpl<7>()
```

As you might expect, `func` and `func_tmpl` are listed as undefined symbols. What I'm not clear on is why `inner` is not listed as well; it is defined inside a class template, is itself a class template, and is instantiated in `main.cpp`. Can anyone suggest the reason for `inner` not being included in the `main.o` symbols, defined or not?

Comment: `nm` does not show classes, it shows functions and global variables. It would show `Box<int>::inner<5>::value` except that it is "unused" here.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thank you for your quick response.  The first sentence of your comment seems reasonable and would explain things.  I'm curious about the second sentence, though: how would I make it "used"?  I've tried a few ways to no apparent avail.  Also, is `Box<int>::inner<5>::value` actually a global variable?  I would have thought it was more narrowly scoped since `::` is required to identify it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler figured out that `Box<int>::inner<5>::value` is a constant, and the object code generation took it out and replaced the name with the literal `5`. If you observe the generated assembly code, you will probably see something like:

```
    movl    $3, -12(%rbp)
    leaq    -12(%rbp), %rdx
    leaq    -13(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN3BoxIiE4funcERKi
    leaq    -13(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN3BoxIiE9func_tmplILi7EEEiv
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $5, -8(%rbp)
```

Which corresponds to the call to `Box::func`, then the call to `Box::func_tmpl` assigned to `x`, and then the assignment to `y`. Notice that the assignment to `y` uses the literal value `5`.

To get the symbol to appear in your `nm` output, use the member itself, not its value. For example, store its reference:

```
    const int &y = g.value;
```

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer.  I didn't consider constant optimizations.  Thanks to you, I will make a point of looking for that next time.  I tried to up vote your answer, but apparently I need a higher reputation first.